# How do I add more fields of information to this particular form and get it to display said information?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is code from a tutorial on RESTful apps that I found online. I would like to add more fields of information including things like DOB and phone number, I have about 25 more fields in total I would like to add. I tried a number of things but couldn't seem to get anything to work. Some insight into how to do this would be appreciated.

global.js file

```
// Userlist data array for filling in info box

var userListData = [];

// DOM Ready =============================================================
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Populate the user table on initial page load
    populateTable();

    // Username link click
    $('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkshowuser', showUserInfo);

    // Add User button click
    $('#btnAddUser').on('click', addUser);

    // Delete User link click
    $('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkdeleteuser', deleteUser);

});

// Functions =============================================================

// Fill table with data
function populateTable() {

    // Empty content string
    var tableContent = '';

    // jQuery AJAX call for JSON
    $.getJSON( '/users/userlist', function( data ) {

        // Stick our user data array into a userlist variable in the global object
        userListData = data;

        // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
        $.each(data, function(){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '" title="Show Details">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
        $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
    });
};

// Show User Info
function showUserInfo(event) {

    // Prevent Link from Firing
    event.preventDefault();

    // Retrieve username from link rel attribute
    var thisUserName = $(this).attr('rel');

    // Get Index of object based on id value
    var arrayPosition = userListData.map(function(arrayItem) { return arrayItem.username; }).indexOf(thisUserName);

    // Get our User Object
    var thisUserObject = userListData[arrayPosition];

    //Populate Info Box
    $('#userInfoName').text(thisUserObject.fullname);
    $('#userInfoAge').text(thisUserObject.age);
    $('#userInfoGender').text(thisUserObject.gender);
    $('#userInfoLocation').text(thisUserObject.location);

};

// Add User
function addUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Super basic validation - increase errorCount variable if any fields are blank
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('#addUser input').each(function(index, val) {
        if($(this).val() === '') { errorCount++; }
    });

    // Check and make sure errorCount's still at zero
    if(errorCount === 0) {

        // If it is, compile all user info into one object
        var newUser = {
            'username': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(),
            'email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
            'fullname': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserFullname').val(),
            'age': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserAge').val(),
            'location': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocation').val(),
            'gender': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserGender').val()
        }

        // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: newUser,
            url: '/users/adduser',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function( response ) {

            // Check for successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {

                // Clear the form inputs
                $('#addUser fieldset input').val('');

                // Update the table
                populateTable();

            }
            else {

                // If something goes wrong, alert the error message that our service returned
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // If errorCount is more than 0, error out
        alert('Please fill in all fields');
        return false;
    }
};

// Delete User
function deleteUser(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Pop up a confirmation dialog
    var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');

    // Check and make sure the user confirmed
    if (confirmation === true) {

        // If they did, do our delete
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/users/deleteuser/' + $(this).attr('rel')
        }).done(function( response ) {

            // Check for a successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {
            }
            else {
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
            }

            // Update the table
            populateTable();

        });

    }
    else {

        // If they said no to the confirm, do nothing
        return false;

    }

};
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to our test

    // Wrapper
    #wrapper

        // USER INFO
        #userInfo
            h2 User Info
            p
                strong Name:
                |  <span id='userInfoName'></span>
                br
                strong Age:
                |  <span id='userInfoAge'></span>
                br
                strong Gender:
                |  <span id='userInfoGender'></span>
                br
                strong Location:
                |  <span id='userInfoLocation'></span>
        // /USER INFO
        // USER LIST
        h2 User List
        #userList
            table
                thead
                    th UserName
                    th Email
                    th Delete?
                tbody
        // /USER LIST
        // ADD USER
        h2 Add User
        #addUser
            fieldset
                input#inputUserName(type='text', placeholder='Username')
                input#inputUserEmail(type='text', placeholder='Email')
                br
                input#inputUserFullname(type='text', placeholder='Full Name')
                input#inputUserAge(type='text', placeholder='Age')
                br
                input#inputUserLocation(type='text', placeholder='Location')
                input#inputUserGender(type='text', placeholder='gender')
                br
                button#btnAddUser Add User
        // /ADD USER
    // /WRAPPER
```

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content
        script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
        script(src='/javascripts/global.js')
```